# Are there any well known algorithms to detect the presence of names?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-processing

For example, given a string:

"Bob went fishing with his friend Jim Smith."

Bob and Jim Smith are both names, but bob and smith are both words. Weren't for them being uppercase, there would be less indication of this outside of our knowledge of the sentence. Are there any well known algorithms for detecting the presence of names, at least Western names?

Comment: Boyer-Moore with pre-computed list of names?

Comment: Interesting, so you'd run the Boyer-Moore once per name in your pre-computed list? I'd guess you can optimize a bit by only searching against names that have the same first letter as the name you're testing for, and then let BM test the last character, and work backwards?

This still doesn't address the ambiguity between names that are also words.

Comment: I've removed the requirement to do without grammar analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Named Entity Recognition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition The article links to two good implementations.

Im not sure if this falls under your definition of grammar analysis though.